# How to pass two arguments in OnChange?

Tags: reactjs, input

I create a table automatically with my data and I need to pass two values to the function `onPred1Change()`, I need the input value and the loop counter `k`

How can I do that ?

```js
<Table striped bordered hover>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Prediction</th>                         
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {Object.keys(this.state.jsondata.label).map(k =>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{k}</td>
                                <td>                
                                    <input
                                        id={'pred' + k}
                                        className="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        value={this.state.jsondata.prediction[k]}
                                        onChange={e => this.onPred1Change(e.target.value)}
                                    />          
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )}                  
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
```

Because I need the `k` to find the index of the data and the `value` to modify this data.

Here is a quick sample where I use the `k`:

```
<Button variant="success" onClick={() => { this.validatePred2(k) }}>Validate <Check/></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with the function, but actually you already do it well.
Just need to passing another argument on the `onPred1Change`

```
<input
      id={'pred' + k}
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      value={this.state.jsondata.prediction[k]}
      onChange={(e) => this.onPred1Change(e.target.value, k)}
/>
```

After that, you need to change the `onPred1Change` to accept two argument also.

So it can be like this:

```
const onPred1Change = (val, k) => {
  console.log(`get the ${val} and ${k}`)
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly thank you :D